# JavaScript post request returning as cancelled

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

```
window.post = function(url, data) {
    return fetch(url, {method: "POST", headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, body: JSON.stringify(data)});
}

post(url, {"rblxtoken": document.getElementById('cookie').value});
```

It keeps returning status cancelled and I don't know why.
[image]

I've also tried this code (which should be the same)

```
let data = {
     "rblxtoken": document.getElementById('cookie').value
}

fetch(url, {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
     },
     body: `{\n    "rblxtoken": 
     "${document.getElementById('cookie').value}"\n}`
});
```

It works perfectly in postman, yet doesn't want to work in my code.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What triggers the `post()` / `fetch()` call? If it's a link / button click or form submission, you've probably forgotten to prevent the default event action. Navigating away from the current page cancels any async requests

Comment: @Phil it's triggered by clicking a button and it refreshes after it cancels. How can I fix this?